# How to convert the HTML5 input date to some format I like?

Tags: php, html, date, input

I collect a date via the HTML5 input field type=date. Saved in a php variable. The format is: yyyy-mm-dd

I want to convert it via php to this, for example: 24 September 2014

It is for a wp shortcode.

Does anyone have an idea? Mayboe there is a way with js/jquery before it is saved to the variable.

HTML:

```
<div class="section clearfix">
    <label for="accordion-date">Title</label>
    <input type="date" id="accordion-date" name="accordion-date" value="" />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
function afo_accordion_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'title' => 'The Accordion Panel Title goes here.',
    'date' => '',
), $atts));

return '<div class="accordion-container"><h5 class="accordion-toggle"><span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-1x"></i></span>' . $title . '<span class="afo-float-right afo-color-1">' . $date . '</span></h5><div class="accordion-content"><p>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p></div></div>';

}

add_shortcode('accordion', 'afo_accordion_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this in PHP:

```
$originalDate = "2014-10-15";
$newDate = date("d F Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```